# how to read the value from IBaseValue Object in python while using the ASAM XiL API Interface?

Tags: python-3.x, python.net

I am just trying to use the ASAM XiL API to create the Model Access(MA)-Port. So, I have created that in python. Now when i am trying to read and write the value of a variable, the read command give the output in the form of IBaseValue Object.

[this is the image in which you can see the attributes and methods of the object 'readValue'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMFi6.png)

And I've read the documentation of the example demos from DSpace and they are using the command like "readValue.Value" for my case. but it turns out that I am getting error like the readValue object doesn't have any aattribute like 'Value'.

So, I dont know how to read the actual value. Maybe I am missing any libraries.

I've read somewhere that I need the library which can support the code written in C# form. but I dont know.

The value is in the datatype float and it turns out that the commands like float(readValue) is also not working here because the 'readValue' is IBaseValue object.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `__raw_implementation__` to get correct object.

```
# Read a value from the probe
raw_probeExp = maPort.Read('Probe1')
probeExp = raw_probeExp.__raw_implementation__
print(str(probeExp.Value))
```

I assume that XIL API assemblies are not fully compatibile with new pythonnet library.
Some more information what changed:
https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#changed-3